# Testing one php based project on my embedded platform

Tags: php, yii

http://pastebin.com/9U2UXRSX

Above link is my index.php file.My project is not redirecting to main page after login without adding second line (echo 'any thing';). But if i add this line its is giving php warning:

Header can't be modify , already sent by blah.blah.. and not working any more.

I don't any thing about php coding, i am just testing one php based apps on my embedded platform.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why are you using echo in index.php?

Answer (score 0):

Remove unwanted space in function page 
u can Use ob_flush()

Comment: Using `ob_*` functions is a terrible advice

Comment: u cant add echo while using include,,,thats y it shows output already sent,,,check whether any echo added in include page

Comment: This error message gets triggered when anything is sent before you send HTTP headers (with setcookie or header). Common reasons for outputting something before the HTTP headers are:

    Accidental whitespace, often at the beginning or end of files, like this:

     <?php
    // Note the space before "<?php"
    ?>

       To avoid this, simply leave out the closing ?> - it's not required anyways.

Comment: I know why it happens. I'm not the OP, I just mentioned that using `ob_*` functions to fix it is a terrible idea.

Comment: Between your two PHP tags you have whitespace.

?>

<?php

This'll cause your headers to be sent before starting any session and sending more headers.

I suggest just removing that bit of code.

Comment: it makes sense to fix the roots of the error not the consequences.

Comment: vignesh Zerkms  If i'll remove echo then the page itself is not directing and giving message:The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.I dont know what is connection b/w redirection of page and echo.